# Remove abridged summary and index values in verbatimTextOutput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using verbatimTextOutput() and renderPrint() in Shiny for summarizing and stating the unique values of a dataset of letter factors. I would like to show all factors in a clean way.

However, when I perform a summary of the data, it only lists the first six factors/letters and then states (Other). Moreover, when I try to list the unique letters of the data, it adds an index in front of each letter. How can I fix these two issues?

I made a MWE to illustrate the problem:

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)

# Load data
data <- data.frame(letters = factor(sample(LETTERS, 200, replace=TRUE)))

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarPanel(
  radioButtons(inputId = "column", label = "Choose a summary column:", choices = colnames(data)),
  radioButtons(inputId = "column2", label = "Choose a unique column:", choices = colnames(data))
),
mainPanel(
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
  verbatimTextOutput("unique")
)
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(data[input$column])
  })

  output$unique <- renderPrint({
    unique(data[input$column2])
  })
}

# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    df <- as.data.frame(summary(data[[input$column]], maxsum = nlevels(data[[input$column]])))
    `names<-`(df, input$column)
  })

  output$unique <- renderPrint({
    cat(as.character(unique(data[[input$column2]])), sep="\n")
  })
}
```

---

### Explanations

#### Summary

**Alternative 1**
The parameter `maxsum` indicates the number of factor levels, which should be shown in the output of the summary

```r
> summary(data[['letters']], maxsum = nlevels(data[['letters']]))
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z 
 7  7 12 12  4 12  2  8  6  6  3  6  6  7  7  6  8 12 12  5 12 11  3  8 10  8
```

Unfortunately, this gives you a named vector as output, which is printed out horizontally instead of vertically.

**Alternative 2**
If you pass the full data.frame to summary, it would give you a nice vertical list of results. The problem here is, if the data.frame has multiple columns and you want to have the summary only for one of the columns, this won't work.

```r
> summary(data, maxsum=nlevels(data[['letters']]))
 letters
 A: 7   
 B: 7   
 C:12   
 D:12   
 E: 4     
 ...
```

**Solution**
This workaround will give you a nice list instead of a horizontal output:

```r
> df <- as.data.frame(summary(data[['letters']], maxsum = nlevels(data[['letters']])))
> `names<-`(df, 'letters')
  letters
A       7
B       7
C      12
D      12
...
```

#### Unique

Following will create a vertical output without indices:

```r
> cat(as.character(unique(data[['letters']])), sep="\n")
J
N
Q
Y
U
Z
...
```

The characters are shown in the order of appearance within the data.

**Sorted**
If you want to sort them, use `sort()`:

```r
> cat(sort(as.character(unique(data[['letters']]))), sep="\n")
A
B
C
D
...
```